# JavaScript addition / sum loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, decimal

I'm trying to add the following but it keeps concatenating and returning a string.

```
    var nums = [1.99, 5.11, 2.99];

    var total = 0;

    nums.forEach(function(i) {
      total += parseFloat(i).toFixed(2);
    });
```

Yes, I need it to return / add it with the decimals. Unsure what to do

Comment: `.toFixed` returns a string, so you're doing `0 + "1.99" + "5.11" + "2.99"`. Instead, add them all up first, then *when displaying the result* use `toFixed`.

Comment: I think you just got the order wrong and meant to do `parseFloat(String(i).toFixed(2));`

Comment: @Amadan you should make an answer out of it. It seems the most complete of everything said here.

Answer (score 7):

If you wanted a more functional approach, you could also use [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
var nums = [1.99, 5.11, 2.99];
var sum = nums.reduce(function(prev, cur) {
  return prev + cur;
}, 0);
```

The last parameter `0`, is an optional starting value.

Comment: You can avoid passing `0` as the second argument.

Comment: @Pavlo: Thanks, I updated my answer with a link to the docs as well as a note about `0` being optional. However, I typically include the optional starting value to make the output of my `reduce` calls easier to reason about.

Answer (score 4):

If you aren't storing strings of floats, you don't need to use parseFloat(i), that parses a float from a string. You could rewrite this as:

```
var nums = [1.99, 5.11, 2.99];

var total = 0;

nums.forEach(function(i) {
  total += i;
});

var fixed = total.toFixed(2);
console.log(fixed);
```

or

```
var nums = [1.99, 5.11, 2.99];

var total = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
  total += nums[i];
}

var fixed = total.toFixed(2);
console.log(fixed);
```

Comment: Call `toFixed(2)` at the end.

Comment: `nums[i]` inside `forEach` must be `i` only as first argument is current element in forEach

Comment: You need to assign the result of `toFixed` to a variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
var nums = [1.99, 5.11, 2.99];

    var total = 0;

    nums.forEach(function(i) {
      total += parseFloat(i);
    });
    alert(total.toFixed(2));
```

Yes, it with the decimals

Answer (score 1):

Try reduce, a recursive option:

```js
    function sum(inputNums) {
      var nums = inputNums;
      var total = nums.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue, index, array) {
        return previousValue + currentValue;
      });
      alert('' + total);
    }
    sum([1.99, 5.11, 2.99]);
```